# Debug keystore for Jenkins and Android build

Tags: android, jenkins

What keystore does jenkins use while building android projects.

Since I use Google Sign-in.
 I need to use the same debug keystore that i use locally.
For that purpose,I have overwritten the `debug.keystore` on the server.
However I am still unable to sign in as the keystore is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Android build system uses a keystore in [`$HOME/.android/debug.keystore`](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debug-mode).

If that file does not exist already at build time, it will be automatically generated.  So most likely the app is being signed with a completely different keystore on your machine and on the Jenkins machine.

You can resolve this by copying the keystore from your machine to the Jenkins machine, to the user `$HOME` directory *that Jenkins runs as*.

---

Alternatively, you can override the default build system behaviour by explicitly supplying a keystore to use when building a debug version of the app.

This means that, no matter user on which machine builds the app, the same debug keystore will always be used to sign the APK.

For example, you can add a new `signingConfig` to `app/build.gradle`:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        // Override the local debug keystore, so that
        // all builds have consistent certificates
        storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
}
```

This assumes that you've created and checked-in a debug keystore at the root of your project.

This debug keystore must have the same key alias and password as the ones that the Android build system generates, i.e. alias `androiddebugkey`, password `android`.

You can use `keytool` to generate a key with these properties:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 \
  -dname 'CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US' -keystore debug.keystore \
  -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android
```

Comment: I dont want to add it to the gradle file.I was hoping of something like shell execution params. And I have replaced that keystore(@ $HOME/.android).However the signatures are not the same.

Comment: If the signatures are not the same, then the keystores are not the same. You can verify this with `keytool -v -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android`.

Comment: So i compared both the md5s.They are the same.could there be another reason that Google  OAuth views them differently?

Comment: Are you sure the `debug.keystore` file is in the right directory (i.e. the `~/.android/` directory of the Jenkins user)? Do the APKs generated on your machine, and by Jenkins have the same certificate fingerprints when you compare with `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk`?

Comment: The jenkins user does not have a shell or home folder or any of those privilleges.I switched users and searched for a `.android` folder, and was pointed to the same folder where i have placed the debug keystore

Comment: The most common way of connecting to a build node in Jenkins (via SSH) doesn't work without a shell or home directory — how is the slave connecting as the Jenkins user? Did the APKs have the same fingerprint? Debug keystore will be searched for in `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME`, the Java `user.home` directory (visible in the node System Information), or `$HOME`. But the easiest solution is still to add a debug keystore to the repository and specify it with Gradle.

Comment: I've done the last option that you have suggested.But I am not comfortable keeping my key there.So will try the other methods you have suggested

Comment: It's a debug keystore. Used for debug builds only. It can't be used for a release and it's not security sensitive. Even storing a release keystore in the repository isn't so bad, so long as the repo is secure, passwords are strong and stored separately.

Comment: Yes ,but you need to provide password params in the build file right?and I would actually fear debug keys more because of the logcat outputs :).

Comment: No, the Gradle snippet in the answer is complete — there's no need to specify passwords, because the build system uses the password `android` by default for debug builds. The location of the debug signing key has nothing to do with security nor logcat output. Good luck.